# "MySQL server has gone away" after a few minutes

Tags: php, mysql, disconnect

I have 2 tables in a query designed to display/email the saved search info of users : users & wishlist.

The search info contains book titles among other things.

I have a first query designed to put into an array all the users that have records in the wishlist table.

Then using a foreach loop, via a second query, take each book title and run a search at various sites and save that information to screen or to an email.

The first run through takes about 3 minutes for the first user's information to be assembled and yet, after this info is displayed, I see the dreaded "MySQL server has gone away".

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html - this shouldn't happen so quickly.

The code for the second query is simple :

```
SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE uid = " . $sendtouser . " ORDER BY wishid
```

After the information is compiled for that user, I have the following to close the loop and end the connection.

```
} while ($row_rsWishDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsWishDetails));
mysql_free_result($rsWishDetails);
```

I have tried some other suggestions I have found on the web including :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 22222);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 500);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);
```

But nothing is fixing the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With long running scripts, you need to make sure that connection is still open before running any queries. The best way to do so is to use something like [`mysql_ping()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) before your query.

Also, the `mysql` is rather old and inefficient. You should try to upgrade to `mysqli`.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) But is 5 minutes really "long running"?  In fact, it's not the query itself that takes a long time, it's the fact that the query has to pause while information is being compiled from the web before moving on.  I thought to add a "sleep(3)" at the end of each user but it didn't do anything.

Comment: The server that we rent space on does not have mysqli installed unfortunately.

Comment: This leaves me with the ping. When do I run this? Just before the query?  Does this mean that before each loop, the ping will be run again? or will it just run the ping once before the query begins?

Comment: 5 minutes is pretty long running, especially if the connection isn't being used. Closing out unused or sleeping MySQL connections is usually a good thing, especially on high traffic MySQL servers. Also, if you feel my answer is correct, it'd be awesome if you could mark it as such!

Answer (score 0):

you need to TEST how many data you can received.

whether your DB machine is old or your result row count is 1000000000000000000000+,
you need to fix your query with paging: limit, cursor, etc...

it is not a direct solution for your question.

first, check your row count with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wishlist WHERE uid = " . $sendtouser . "
```

- ORDER BY is not needed.

check remove ORDER BY phrase and if OK, re-arrangement with PHP code. sometimes it could be helpful.

AND...

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 22222);
```

it is client(PHP) configuration as you know, it's useless if mysql-server not permitted.

Comment: I can tell you the row count.  Right now there are only 3 users.  And the row count is less than 15 for the user with the most records in the wishlist table.

Comment: @Aethon
oops, at least, it not a query problem but looks network problem.
can you check this command in the machine running PHP?

    telnet mysql_server_host_ip 3306 <return>

if take long time, it's network problem. or...?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I think that the time it's waiting to get the results from the web is what is causing the problem.  I wonder if a wait_timeout might help?

Comment: @Aethon yes, i checked again your question, it's connection persist problem. and 'Chris Henry' gave you a solution.
mysql will close php connection because php no action(additional query) and occupied server-connection. so ping() is very useful for persist connection.
it's same as check heartbeat. it will work well. BUT, if you don't want use ping, check option 'mysqli.reconnect' OR check mysql-server configuration to change client persistent time (but, you can not access to rent machine)
anyway, you solved problem. good luck.